# Somando valores POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql

Tenho uma tabela `historicos`:

```
          historicos
id | problemas | total | data
---|-----------|-------|------------
01 |    25     |  125  | 2017-01-01
---|-----------|-------|------------
03 |    25     |  125  | 2017-03-01
---|-----------|-------|------------
04 |    25     |  125  | 2017-04-01
---|-----------|-------|------------
08 |    25     |  125  | 2017-08-01
---|-----------|-------|------------
09 |    25     |  125  | 2017-09-01
---|-----------|-------|------------
10 |    25     |  125  | 2017-10-01
---|-----------|-------|------------
12 |    25     |  125  | 2017-12-01
```

Preciso imprimir os meses pares com a soma dos campos `problemas` e `total`, ou seja, por exemplo, preciso exibir a soma do mês 1 com o mês 2, do mês 3 com o mês 4, do mês 5 com 6 e assim sucessivamente...

Veja o `Fiddle` de exemplo abaixo:

[SQL FIDDLE DE EXEMPLO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ec6d5/1)

*Se falhar o link, tente abrir novamente!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu acredito que uma forma de fazer isso seria ter o número do mês na tabela de historicos, mais como não tem, então teria que ser por data de inicio e fim:

```
select 
case mes
 when 1 then (select sum(problemas), sum(total) from tbhistoricos where data between '2016-01-01' and '2016-02-28'  
else
  0
end as 1Mes,
case mes
 when 2 then (select sum(problemas), sum(total) from tbhistoricos where data between '2016-03-01' and '2016-02-28'  
else
  0
end as 2Mes
from tbhistoricos
```

Comment: Realmente assim funciona, mas não com dois valores dentro da `subquery`, agora estou usando a mesma lógica para fazer com o outro valor, um com `problemas` e outro com `total`

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver utilizando a versão 9.4 do postgres, ou superior, você pode utilizar a cláusula FILTER, que utiliza menos código que o CASE e segue o padrão SQL 2003.

Segue exemplo abaixo:

```
select 
  sum(problemas) filter (where data between '2017-01-01' and '2017-02-28') as problemas_mes_1,
  sum(total) filter (where data between '2017-01-01' and '2017-02-28') as total_mes_1,
  sum(problemas) filter (where data between '2017-03-01' and '2017-04-30') as problemas_mes_2,
  sum(total) filter (where data between '2017-03-01' and '2017-04-30') as total_mes_2
from historicos;
```

Referência:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Camilo, mas eu tentei aqui e não funcionou, da erro de sintaxe quando abre o `(` após o `FILTER`

Comment: Talvez seja a versão do teu postgres, realizei o teste em uma base rodando a versão 9.6. O `FILTER` foi implementado a partir da versão 9.4.

Comment: Achei que pudesse ser também, mas olhei aqui e estou com a 9.5.6 :/

Comment: Pior q no sqlfiddle a versão é a 9.3, ficou ruim pra eu te mandar os mesmos dados que utilizei no meu teste :/

Comment: Pois é, pensei no mesmo ontem :|
Mas posta como resposta, daí eu testo na minha máquina pra ver se tem algo de diferente!